# SAS- Split Dataset based on values in a column (character) and then further split each of these datasets based on a time column

Tags: sas

I have stock trading data for a day - about 60 million rows. Basically, I want to create a dataset that lists the average duration for each 5-minute interval for each of the stocks.

**Dataset Original**

| Obs | time | symbol | tradePrice | tradeId | datatime | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 093000154451968 | A | 152.24 | 7.1675E13 | 1943170200.2 | . |
| 2 | 093000845296640 | A | 151.99 | 5.2984E13 | 1943170200.8 | 0.69084 |
| 3 | 093000845296640 | A | 151.99 | 5.2984E13 | 1943170200.8 | 0.00000 |
| 4 | 093000846918400 | A | 151.99 | 5.2984E13 | 1943170200.8 | 0.00162 |
| 5 | 093000847665152 | A | 151.94 | 6.2879E13 | 1943170200.8 | 0.00075 |
| 6 | 093000847675136 | A | 151.94 | 6.2879E13 | 1943170200.8 | 0.00001 |
| 7 | 093000857328128 | A | 151.94 | 5.2984E13 | 1943170200.9 | 0.00965 |
| 8 | 093000889283840 | A | 151.24 | 7.1675E13 | 1943170200.9 | 0.03196 |
| 9 | 093001249114624 | A | 151.74 | 7.1675E13 | 1943170201.2 | 0.35983 |
| 10 | 093001824934912 | A | 151.99 | 7.1675E13 | 1943170201.8 | 0.57582 |
| 11 | 093001834587904 | A | 151.71 | 5.2989E13 | 1943170201.8 | 0.00965 |
| 12 | 093002261742336 | A | 151.99 | 7.1675E13 | 1943170202.3 | 0.42715 |

Here "time" variable is setup as `hhmmssnnnnnnnnn` (n indicates nanoseconds - i.e. seconds are counted for 9 significant digits after decimal)
and "datetime" variable is converted to nanoseconds using date and time both.
For this code, I only work with one day of data so use "time" variable only.

**Final Result**

| Stock | TimeInterval | Average duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0930-0935 | 23456 |
| A | 0935-0940 | 56789 |
| A | ........ | ...... |
| A | 1555-1600 | 57689 |
| B | 0930-0935 | 23456 |
| B | 0935-0940 | 56789 |
| B | ........ | ...... |
| B | 1555-1600 | 57689 |
| .. | ... | ... |
| Z | 0930-0935 | 23456 |
| Z | 0935-0940 | 56789 |
| Z | ........ | ...... |
| Z | 1555-1600 | 57689 |

Step 1:

I want to split the dataset such that I have a separate dataset for each of the stock symbols. I did this already.

Step 2:

To sum up the values in a column for every 5-minute interval from 0930 to 1600. I am struggling here.

**Current Code:**

```
/* Read Dataset */
   DATA working_dataset;
   set "C:\EQY_US_ALL_TRADE_202107\test_sample_sorted";
   run;

/* List of Unique Symbols and feed them into new variables */
   proc sql noprint;
   select distinct symbol into :symbol1 - (NOTRIM)
   from working_dataset;
   %put &symbol1;
   %put &symbol2;

/* Count of Unique Symbols and store the value in variable "n" */
   proc sql noprint;
   select count(distinct symbol) into: n
   from working_dataset;
   %put &n;

/* Keeping the variables needed for the analysis */
   DATA working_dataset_2;
   SET working_dataset (keep = symbol time duration tradePrice datetime tradeId);
   run;


/* Extracting stock symbol names from the dataset;*/

    proc sort data=working_dataset_2 out=symblist (keep = symbol)
    nodupkey;
    by symbol;
    run;

/* Creating multiple datasets from the parent dataset;*/
    data _null_;
    set symblist;
    call execute('data ' !! compress(symbol) !! '; set working_dataset_2; where symbol = "' !! symbol !! '"; run;');
    run;
```

For Step 2:

I don't know how to but I am planning to run a loop for 78x 5 minute intervals between 0930 to 1600 using an if statement controlled by the loop value. The following is just wishful thinking - not code. I don't know where to begin.

```
data dataset_final;
set "A"; /* To be changed as per variable for stock symbol */
array symb(&n); /* this array should have all the stock symbols */
do over; /* do over for all the array items in the array symb(&n) */
do i = 1 to 78;
if (time GE (093000000000000 + &i.- 1)) & (time LT (093000000000000 + &i.))
then send obs to symb_j_0930+&i.-1
end;
```

Any help is appreciated. I am not sure how to attach the datafile.

Step 1 works. I am able to create different datasets using and call/execute.

Log for Step 1:

```
439
440  DATA working_dataset;
441  set "C:\EQY_US_ALL_TRADE_202107\test_sample_sorted";
442  run;

NOTE: There were 50000 observations read from the data set
      C:\EQY_US_ALL_TRADE_202107\test_sample_sorted.
NOTE: The data set WORK.WORKING_DATASET has 50000 observations and 25 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.12 seconds
      cpu time            0.09 seconds


443
444  proc sql noprint;
445  select distinct symbol into :symbol1 - (NOTRIM)
                                            -
                                            22
                                            76
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ',', :, FROM, NOTRIM.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

446  from working_dataset;
447  %put &symbol1;
A
448  %put &symbol2;
AA
449
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
      real time           0.03 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds



450  proc sql noprint;
451  select count(distinct symbol) into: n
452  from working_dataset;
453  %put &n;
2
454
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
      real time           0.04 seconds
      cpu time            0.04 seconds


455  DATA working_dataset_2;
456  SET working_dataset (keep = symbol time duration tradePrice datetime tradeId);
457
458  /* Extracting stock symbol names from the dataset;*/

NOTE: There were 50000 observations read from the data set WORK.WORKING_DATASET.
NOTE: The data set WORK.WORKING_DATASET_2 has 50000 observations and 6 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


459  proc sort data=working_dataset_2 out=symblist (keep = symbol)
460  nodupkey;
461  by symbol;
462  run;

NOTE: There were 50000 observations read from the data set WORK.WORKING_DATASET_2.
NOTE: 49998 observations with duplicate key values were deleted.
NOTE: The data set WORK.SYMBLIST has 2 observations and 1 variables.
NOTE: PROCEDURE SORT used (Total process time):
      real time           0.03 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds


463  /* Creating multiple datasets from the parent dataset;*/
464  data _null_;
465  set symblist;
466  call execute('data ' !! compress(symbol) !! '; set working_dataset_2; where symbol = "' !! symbol
466!  !! '"; run;');
467  run;

NOTE: There were 2 observations read from the data set WORK.SYMBLIST.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


NOTE: CALL EXECUTE generated line.
1   + data A; set working_dataset_2; where symbol = "A                "; run;

NOTE: There were 24304 observations read from the data set WORK.WORKING_DATASET_2.
      WHERE symbol='A                ';
NOTE: The data set WORK.A has 24304 observations and 6 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds


2   + data AA; set working_dataset_2; where symbol = "AA               "; run;

NOTE: There were 25696 observations read from the data set WORK.WORKING_DATASET_2.
      WHERE symbol='AA               ';
NOTE: The data set WORK.AA has 25696 observations and 6 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.02 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

Step 2 is where I am horribly struggling. I am not sure how to do the code.

Comment: I don't understand why you need a loop. It does not look like your time intervals are overlapping, why not just either convert the values to the start of the interval or use a format so you can just group by the interval without any looping?

Comment: Why are you calling the SUM an AVERAGE?  Which calculation are actually trying to do?  Find the sum or the average?

Comment: @Tom - I may be wrong in using the loop. What I am trying to do is say for Stock "A" there are 6 trades (with "duration" values - 4,6,7,12,3,6) in 5 minute interval of 0935 - 0940. I want the final dataset to have a corresponding entry of Stock "A" , time interval "0935-0940" and Average Duration to be calculated as (4+6+7+12+3+6)/6 = 38/6 = 6.33.  This needs to be repeated for all 5 minute intervals and all stocks.

Comment: So you want the MEAN of the values, not the SUM of the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an actual time value (you can create one from your first 16 digit string) you can just convert that time to the start of the 5 minute interval and use that to group the data.  No need for looping (or splitting).

Let's modify your example data so it actually has more than one stock symbol and more than one time interval.  You can convert the first 6 characters of your TIME string into an actual TIME value.  Which we can then convert to the beginning of the 5 minute interval.

```
data have ;
  input time :$16. symbol :$4. tradePrice tradeId datatime duration;
  tod = input(time,hhmmss6.);
  interval='00:05:00't*int(tod/'00:05:00't);
  format tod interval tod8.;
  nanosec = input(substr(time,7),32.);
cards;
093000154451968 A 152.24 7.1675E13 1943170200.2 .
093000845296640 A 151.99 5.2984E13 1943170200.8 0.69084
093500845296640 A 151.99 5.2984E13 1943170200.8 0.00000
093500846918400 A 151.99 5.2984E13 1943170200.8 0.00162
093800847665152 A 151.94 6.2879E13 1943170200.8 0.00075
093000847675136 B 151.94 6.2879E13 1943170200.8 0.00001
093100857328128 B 151.94 5.2984E13 1943170200.9 0.00965
093900889283840 B 151.24 7.1675E13 1943170200.9 0.03196
093001249114624 C 151.74 7.1675E13 1943170201.2 0.35983
093301824934912 C 151.99 7.1675E13 1943170201.8 0.57582
093801834587904 C 151.71 5.2989E13 1943170201.8 0.00965
094102261742336 C 151.99 7.1675E13 1943170202.3 0.42715
;
```

So once you have a dataset (or even a view) that has the three variables needed, SYBMOL INTERVAL and DURATION, you can then just use PROC SUMMARY to produce the mean of the durations.

```
proc summary nway ;
  class symbol interval;
  var duration;
  output out=want mean=mean_duration ;
run;
```

Results:

```
                                                   mean_
Obs    symbol    interval    _TYPE_    _FREQ_    duration

 1       A       09:30:00       3         2       0.69084
 2       A       09:35:00       3         3       0.00079
 3       B       09:30:00       3         2       0.00483
 4       B       09:35:00       3         1       0.03196
 5       C       09:30:00       3         2       0.46783
 6       C       09:35:00       3         1       0.00965
 7       C       09:40:00       3         1       0.42715
```

Comment: Thanks. That is a smart way to look at my problem. I will do the code and get my feedback to you. This looks like very low CPU usage. Thanks again!

Comment: This works great. I won't have to make separate datasets and it's super quick. Thanks!

Comment: You could also create a format that groups the data into the intervals.  Then you could run against the existing dataset without having to create a new variable.

Answer (score 1):

You say you're struggling with Step 2: "To sum up the values in a column for every 5-minute interval from 0930 to 1600. I am struggling here."

I'm just going to address that part of your question based on looking at the final result that you want. I'm providing code so you don't need to split the data into multiple datasets of each stock.

```
data final;
  set <dataset>;
  time_interval = intck("minute", "09:30:00", tradetime);
  time_interval = time_interval - mod(time_interval, 5);
run;

proc sql;
    select stock, time_interval, avg(duration) as avg_duration
    from final
    group by stock, time_interval;
quit;
```

But, if you want to keep multiple datasets by stock, then just remove the "stock" variable from the code and apply this to every stock dataset you have.

Comment: Thanks @linstar. Your approach seems so much smarter than what I thought. I will try this code and get the feedback to you.

Comment: Both of the solution work. Stack does not allow both of them to be the accepted for some reason.

Comment: NP, glad it worked!